# useState([]) returns undefined instead of empty array using context

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, react-context

I am quite new to react and i´m tryng to make a wishlist using context. I have done something similar for my cart so I coppied all the code from there, but I cannot figure out why this is not working. When I call the array "wishlist" it returns undefined instead of an empty array despite having used useState([]) in the wishlist Context. (I DID THE SAME WITH THE CART AND WORKS PERFECTLY!) Here I leave the code:

wishlistContext.js

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const WishlistContext = createContext([]);

export const useWishlistContext = () => useContext(WishlistContext);

export const WishlistProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [wishlist, setWishlist] = useState([]); // HERE I SET "wishlist" AS AN EMPTY ARRAY

  const value = {
    wishlist,
  };

  return (
    <WishlistContext.Provider value={value} displayName="wishlistContext">
      {children}
    </WishlistContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Wishlist.jsx

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useWishlistContext } from "../context/wishlistContext";

export const Wishlist = () => {
  const { wishlist } = useWishlistContext();
  console.log(wishlist); // THIS IS WHAT RETURNS UNDEFINED

  return (
    <div className="w-75 m-auto my-5">
      Something
    </div>
  );
};
```

NOW I LEAVE THE SAME EXAMPLE WITH CART THAT WORKS FLAWLESSLY

cartContext.js

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const CartContext = createContext([]);

export const useCartContext = () => useContext(CartContext);

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]); // HERE I SET "cart" AS AN EMPTY ARRAY

  const removeProduct = (id) => {
    const newCart = cart.filter((product) => product.id !== id);
    setCart(newCart);
  };

  const addProduct = (item, qty) => {
    const element = cart.find((product) => product.id === item.id);

    if (!element) return setCart([...cart, { ...item, qty }]);

    const newCart = cart.map((product) => {
      if (product.id === item.id) {
        return { ...product, qty: product.qty + qty };
      }
      return product;
    });
    setCart(newCart);
  };

  const getTotal = () =>
    cart.reduce((acc, product) => acc + product.valor * product.qty, 0);

  const getCartQty = () => cart.reduce((acc, product) => acc + product.qty, 0);

  const emptyCart = () => setCart([]);

  const value = {
    cart,
    addProduct,
    removeProduct,
    getCartQty,
    getTotal,
    emptyCart,
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={value} displayName="cartContext">
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Cart.jsx

```js
import { BsFillCartFill } from "react-icons/bs";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { addOrder } from "../api/orders";
import { updateManyProducts } from "../api/products";
import { useCartContext } from "../context/cartContext";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

export const Cart = () => {
  const { getTotal, cart, emptyCart } = useCartContext();

  console.log(cart);

  if (cart.length <= 0)
    return (
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-evenly">
        <div className="text-center m-auto" style={{ fontWeight: 600 }}>
          <BsFillCartFill /> <br /> Su carrito esta vacío
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  const createOrder = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const items = cart.map(({ id, nombre, qty, valor }) => ({
      id,
      nombre,
      qty,
      valor,
    }));

    let itemsAlert = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      itemsAlert +=
        "<b>Item:</b> " +
        items[i].nombre +
        "<br><b>Cantidad:</b> " +
        items[i].qty +
        " <b>Valor Unidad:</b> $" +
        items[i].valor +
        "<br><br>";
      console.log(itemsAlert);
    }

    const order = {
      buyer: { name, phone, email },
      items,
      fecha: newdate,
      estado: { orderState },
      total: getTotal(),
    };
    const { buyer, fecha, total } = order;

    const id = await addOrder(order);

    await updateManyProducts(items);
    emptyCart();

    Swal.fire({
      title: "Pedido Realizado",
      html: `El id de su compra es <b>"${id}"</b> <br> Fecha: ${fecha}<br><br> <b>Detalle de compra:</b><br> <br> <b>Comprador:</b> ${buyer.name} <br><br> ${itemsAlert}<br> <b>Total: $${total}</b>`,
      icon: "success",
      confirmButtonText: "OK",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-75 m-auto my-5">
      <h2 className="text-center my-5">
        <BsFillCartFill /> Carrito <BsFillCartFill />{" "}
      </h2>

      {cart.map((product) => (
        <div
          key={product.id}
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            gap: 50,
            height: 100,
            alignItems: "center",
            width: "70%",
            justifyContent: "space-evenly",
          }}
          className="m-auto"
        >
          <div>
            Producto :{" "}
            <b>
              <b>{product.nombre}</b>
            </b>
          </div>
          <div>
            Valor unitario :{" "}
            <b>
              <b>${product.valor}</b>
            </b>
          </div>
          <div>
            Cantidad :{" "}
            <b>
              <b>{product.qty}</b>
            </b>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <span
        style={{
          marginBottom: 50,
          textAlign: "center",
          width: "70%",
          fontSize: 20,
        }}
        className="mx-auto"
      >
        Total :{" "}
        <b>
          <b>${getTotal()}</b>
        </b>
      </span>
      <form style={{ display: "grid", gap: 10 }} className="mb-5">
        <span>Nombre</span>
        <input
          style={{ border: "1px solid black", height: 40 }}
          onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <span>Telefono</span>
        <input
          type={"phone"}
          style={{ border: "1px solid black", height: 40 }}
          onBlur={(e) => validateInput(e.target.value, "phone")}
        />
        <span>Email</span>
        <input
          type={"email"}
          style={{ border: "1px solid black", marginBottom: 15, height: 40 }}
          onBlur={(e) => validateInput(e.target.value, "email")}
        />
        <span>Confirmar Email</span>
        <input
          style={{ border: "1px solid black", marginBottom: 15, height: 40 }}
          onBlur={(e) => checkEmail(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onClick={createOrder} />
      </form>

      <div>
        {mailError}
        <br />
        {phoneError}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I dont know if this has to do with some async property that i´m missing. Truth is I literally replicated the  cart code, and this outcome really surprised me. Thank you all beforehand, this is giving me a big headache.

Comment: I cannot repro this.  I get an empty array logged. https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-dream-cqc0cg?file=/src/wishlist.jsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSX component must be wrapped by the context provider. Not sure if that is the issue without seeing the parent of your Wishlist component. Here is how I recreated the project and resolved issue:

Create React App 5.0.1

1. `npx create-react-app test`
2. `cd test`
3. `npm start`
4. Copy wishlistContext.js to src/context/
5. Copy wishlist.jsx to src/
6. To reproduce the issue, modify App.js to the following:

```
    import './App.css';
    import { Wishlist } from './wishList';

    function App() {
      return (
        <Wishlist />
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

7. See `undefined` in the console
8. Wrap the JSX element with the context provider

```
    import './App.css';
    import { Wishlist } from './wishList';
    import { WishlistProvider } from './context/wishlistContext';

    function App() {
      return (
            <WishlistProvider>
              <Wishlist />
            </WishlistProvider>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

9. See `[]` in the console

Comment: Yes Sir! That was it, thank you very much. I wasn´t aware of that context provider parent.
god bless you haha!